# Mysql + ASP how to add a record

Tags: javascript, mysql, asp-classic

My asp (and js) code works good but i don't know the exact command to INSERT a record into a DB. I'm able to "read", "update" and "delete" from db, but not insert!
(db server values are example)

```
var Cn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");

Cn.Open("server=1.1.1.1;db=dbserver; DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};uid=login;pwd=password");

var value1 = new String(Request.Form("value1"));
var value1 = new String(Request.Form("value1"));
var value1 = new String(Request.Form("value1"));

    Cn.Execte("INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (value1,value2,value3)");

    Cn.Close();
    Response.Redirect("home.asp");
```

Can someone help me?

thanks!

Comment: VB doesn't interpolate variables and SQL values usually need quotes around them, but if you fixed that you'd be vulnerable to SQL injection. Go and read http://bobby-tables.com/asp.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have concatenate the values into the sql string like :

```
Cn.Execute("INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3) VALUES ('" + value1 + "','" + value2 + "','" + value3 + "')");
```

The `'` are used assuming the columns in the db are strings, otherwise you don't need it.

Comment: No, the entire procedure seems not work:
[MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.5.37-35.1-log]PROCEDURE mysqlserver.Execte does not exist

Comment: you have typo there : it is `Execute` , not `Execte`

Answer (score 0):

If value paramaters are string - nvarchar, text etc.

You must enclose them into quotes. Your statement must look like this.

```
Cn.Execute("INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (value1,'" + value2 + "','" + value3 + "')");
```

I assumed col2 and col3 are string types and col1 isn't.

Comment: No, the entire procedure seems not work:
[MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.5.37-35.1-log]PROCEDURE mysqlserver.Execte does not exist